# I want to add"some scrolling news" on particular standard object.How is it possible?

Tags: visualforce, scrolling

How do we get a news feed on the page.My requirement is if I click one record, some news regarding that record should be scrolled on my page.How do I code it??

Comment: Need more Clarification, Probably this can be done using Visualforce Page - code it separately as per your requirements and add that VF on your pagelayout with new section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery Webticker by Jonathan](http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/)  in your visualforce.

Comment: in simple words,my page should contain a 'news' scroll beside the object deatails in the page